# php 32 byte length secure hash

Tags: php, hash, md5

I need an hash function that produces a 32 byte length hash.
I cannot use MD5 as it's insecure.
So I've checked the php algorithms provided by the `hash_algos()` function.
Thanks to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) post I've found only three algorithms that produce 32 byte length hash:

- Haval 128,5
- Tiger 128,3
- Ripemd 128

But I've found that all of them aren't secure. 
For the haval 128 has been found some collisions. Indeed I found:

> The attack break the full HAVAL-128 
>   source: http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/6N00C0KC0Q.html

for the Tiger algorithm I've found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29) that no collisions has been found for the 24 round version of the algorithm. But the 24 round version of the algorithm is the tiger192,4 that gives 48 length hash.

Finally, for the ripemd 128, always on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD), I've found

> In August 2004, a collision was reported for the original RIPEMD. This does not apply to RIPEMD-160.

So do you know if there is a valid secure replacement in for md5 hash that produces the same length hash?

Comment: "Secure" by itself doesn't mean much. The question to ask is, *secure against what*? How are you going to be using this hash function? Why are you constrained to 32 characters? Why are you even talking about "characters" instead of bytes?

Comment: What do you actually need this for? Collision risk may not be as critical as you seem to think, depending on your purpose. If it's for file hashing to identify changes, then it's probably adequate; if it's for passwords, then you shouldn't be relying on a simple unsalted hash of any kind

Comment: i don't know any possibility to achieve that. why is it necessary that it must have a length of 32?

Comment: If security is a concern, using a salt when computing the hash (whichever it might be) is always advisable.

Comment: Just use the hash that allows you to control the generated size: [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) allows you to specify the hash of a given size. Just make sure that delimiter count + delim length + hash length === 32

Comment: @Roberto ***If*** we're talking about password storage. I'm not sure that we are. Hashes don't always go with salts, they're not automagically applicable to every situation.

Comment: @deceze Secure storage is not limited to passwords...

Comment: @Robert And hashes aren't limited to secure storage.

Comment: @deceze LastYorsh quite explicitly asks about SECURE hashes.

Comment: @Roberto As others have asked: *"secure"* for what purpose?! You can't just say "secure" and have it mean something. You can't say "secure" and assume it's about passwords. You can't say "secure" and associate it with "salt". Those are all different things. Maybe the OP *should* be using a salt here or not, we simply don't have sufficient information to say one way or another, because we have no clue what the use case is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the 24 round version of the algorithm is the tiger192,4 that gives 48 length hash.

The `tiger192,4` version is actually 32 rounds instead of 24 (which is `tiger192,3` iirc); so why not just use that, but encode the result with base-64?

```
$data = 'hello';
echo base64_encode(hash('tiger192,4', $data, true));
// 6OUOI5+TKhw1cZTl6tD1KNwq6/6u0Bx0
```

The `hash()` function is asked to return the raw result which is then passed to `base64_encode()`; it will exactly fit 32 bytes. The same would apply when you use `hash_hmac()`.

This assumes you're not using this for password hashing, because you should be using the [password api](http://php.net/password) for that imo.